# Writing in Pycharm is possible only for 1 second when double-clicked

Tags: pycharm

I am not able to write anything in Pycharm. Only when I double-click I can type for about 1 second and then the typing is blocked until I double-click again.  The same happens in Pycharm Terminal. Also, when I click the right mouse button the drop-down menu closes itself after a second so that I am often unable to select an option in time.

- I have Tools -> Vim Emulator unchecked
- In Tools -> Vim Emulator in Properties -> Keymap -> Editor Actions -> Toggle Insert Overwrite, I have set it, but that's not it either.
- I have disabled 'block caret' in Properties -> Editor-> General-> Appearance

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Previously everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable IdeaVim

[image]

You will see "V" in the footer. Click it and Make sure "enable" is unchecked.

If nothing works, please disable/delete all plugins and try again. It should work.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't fix the issue. The problem is that the cursor while typing disappearing after a second and then I am not able to type